# Is it possible to mark TCP streams in Windows?

Tags: windows, tcp, registry

Hi and I have the following question:

Is it possible to mark TCP streams (outgoing packets only is OK) for Windows 7?

Plainly speaking how to configure TCP stack to automatically add a TCP header extension with a specific 32bit value for every outgoing TCP packet system wide?

I need to recognize the particular stream's source (device) after NAT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [raw sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These sockets give you access to the underlying protocols which "normal" sockets hide.

I've never used them but it may be worth investigating ... good luck!

Comment: I don;t thing so. The question implies no programming or 3rd party code involved. What I need is to inform Windows TCP stack to automatically add some custom extension for TCP headers. I don't know if such a thing ever possible.